# Get around Tastypie ignoring queryset on ManyToMany query

Tags: django-queryset, django-orm, tastypie

I am having trouble getting Tastypie to behave properly with ManyToMany queries.

Here is a simplified version of my models.

```python
class Buttons(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    deleted = models.IntegerField()
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    jacket = models.ManyToManyField('Jackets', through='JacketsButtons', related_name='buttons_jackets', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'habby'
        db_table = u'buttons'

#joining table
class JacketsButtons(models.Model):
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField()
    jacket_id = models.ForeignKey('Jackets')
    button_id = models.ForeignKey('Buttons')
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'habby'
        db_table = u'jacket_buttons'

class Jackets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=450, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField()
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'habby'
        db_table = u'jackets'
```

And these are the Resource models:

```python
class ButtonsResource(ModelResource):
    jacket = fields.ToManyField('habby.JacketsResource', "jacket", null=True, readonly=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Buttons.objects.filter(jacketsbuttons__deleted=0)
        resource_name = 'buttons'
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
                "id": ALL,
                "name": ALL,
                "deleted" : ALL,
                "date_entered" : ALL,
                "date_modified" : ALL,
                "jacket" : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

class JacketsResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Jackets.objects.filter(deleted=0)
        resource_name = 'jackets'
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
                "id": ALL,
                "name": ALL,
                "deleted" : ALL,
                "date_entered" : ALL,
                "date_modified" : ALL,
        }
```

Now, What I am trying to do is filter buttons, by one parameter on the joining table and one on the jackets table, which works perfectly in django:

```python
Buttons.objects.filter(
        jacket__id="1",
        jacketsbuttons__deleted=0)
```

But I can't figure out how to do the equivalent in TastyPie.

I have tried this:

```python
GET /api/v1/buttons/?jacket__id=1&jacketsbuttons__deleted=0
```

But TastyPie ignores the jacketsbuttons__deleted parameter as it is removed in Resource.build_filters() as it is not found in self.fields.

So then I tried the setup that I showed above where I specify the condition as part of the queryset in the meta class, and which brings me to the topic of this question.

When querying the resource and specifying the jacket__id, it completely ignores the queryset and as a result, the joining table filter.

```python
...
class Meta:
            queryset = Buttons.objects.filter(jacketsbuttons__deleted=0)
...

GET /api/v1/buttons/?jacket__id=1
```

But when I substitute the jacket__id parameter for another native button parameter, or even leave out all parameters it works fine, the joining table filter is used correctly.

```python
GET /api/v1/buttons/?name=round_button
```

I also tried the "Per-Request Alterations To The Queryset" as suggested in the [TastyPie Cookbook](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/docs/cookbook.rst), but it also was ignored as soon as I tried to query by jacket__id:

```python
class Meta:
        queryset = Buttons.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(ButtonsResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(jacketsbuttons__deleted=0)
```

So, why is it being ignored?
How can I force it to be used?

Also, does anyone else know of a better what to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Jayd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar scenario before, and what I did then is to modify apply_filter function to something like this:

```
def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
    """
    accept extra query in request
    """
    query_foo = request.GET.get('foo', None)
    query_bar = request.GET.get('bar', None)
    semi_filtered = super(RouteResource, self).apply_filters(request, applicable_filters)
    if query_foo:
        filtered_objects = semi_filtered.filter(..something with query_foo..)
        return filtered_objects
    else:
        return semi_filtered
```

you can always take a look at resource code of tastypie to see how this function works. Hope it helps.